# Why I can open youtube html page in python but can't in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

I open youtube search page in html.

I use python 3:

`from urllib.request import urlopen
urlopen('http://youtube.com/results?search_query=test').read()`

And ruby 2:

`require 'net/http'
 Net::HTTP.get('www.youtube.com','/results?search_query=test')`

The second way works at first my computer but don't works at second. Request returns empty string, also I saw message '301 moved...'

How could I open youtube html in ruby? Where are these errors?

**UPDATED:**

Yes, `request 'open-uri'` helps.Thanks.

Comment: because Python rocks! no seriously, if the status code returned as `301`, it means **moved permanently** -- likely from **http** to **https**, which you need to follow the redirect in order to *READ*.

Comment: My guess is that urllib in python automatically follows the 301 redirect, whereas the ruby request does not automatically follow it. I don't know much (read: anything) about ruby, so that's just a guess. @Anzel is probably right about the https too.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has moved permanently to a secure `https` domain. I'm assuming the python lib you are using (urllib) automatically detects the redirect, and the ruby one doesn't. I'd say it would be best to include the `https` in your URL string, so this:

```
require 'net/http'  
Net::HTTP.get('https://www.youtube.com','/results?search_query=test')
```

should work.

If it doesn't (which will depend on the 'net/http' library which i don't know), check this method out. It's a completely different approach but it works for me

```
html = `curl https://youtube.com/results?search_query=test`
```

The backticks runs a command directly on the OS terminal. So the direct output from `cUrl`, which is the html returned from the web page, will be saved to the variable `html`.
Note that it will only work on a Unix machine